# Formula to create a row for every value of a comma-delimited list - GSheets

Tags: google-sheets, join, split, flatten, textjoin

I am trying to write a formula that will take a set of columns and pair them into separate rows with a comma-delimited list. In SQL, I would do this with a left join, but I am not sure how to leverage GSheets functions for this.

Here is what I mean:

**Source Data**

| Col1 | Col2 | CommaDelim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col1Val1 | Col2Val1 | 1,2,3 |
| Col1Val2 | Col2Val2 | 1 |
| Col1Val3 | Col2Val3 | 1,2 |
| Col1Val4 | Col2Val4 | 1,2,3,4 |

**Desired Output**

| Col1 | Col2 | CommaDelim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col1Val1 | Col2Val1 | 1 |
| Col1Val1 | Col2Val1 | 2 |
| Col1Val1 | Col2Val1 | 3 |
| Col1Val2 | Col2Val2 | 1 |
| Col1Val3 | Col2Val3 | 1 |
| Col1Val3 | Col2Val3 | 2 |
| Col1Val4 | Col2Val4 | 1 |
| Col1Val4 | Col2Val4 | 2 |
| Col1Val4 | Col2Val4 | 3 |
| Col1Val4 | Col2Val4 | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:A&"×"&B1:B&"×"&SPLIT(C1:C, ",")), "×"), 
 "where Col3 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you. I changed INDEX to ARRAYFORMULA though- I think they are serving the same purpose here?

Comment: @RJE yes, they are